# Can not evaluate value of the property via lldb

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, lldb

In my class I have a property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *allMediaButton;
```

in my code I enable and disable this control using `setEnabled:` setter.

But in debug window I can not check the property value

I tried it in different ways:

```
(lldb) po (UIBarItem*)appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton
(UIBarItem *) $1 = 0x08302ed0 <UIBarButtonItem: 0x8302ed0>

(lldb) po (UIBarItem*)appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton.enabled
error: property 'enabled' not found on object of type 'UIBarButtonItem *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) expr (UIBarItem*)appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton.enabled
error: property 'enabled' not found on object of type 'UIBarButtonItem *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) expr ((UIBarItem*)appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton).enabled
error: property 'enabled' not found on object of type 'UIBarItem *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) expr ((UIBarItem*)appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton).enabled
error: property 'enabled' not found on object of type 'UIBarItem *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) po ((UIBarItem*)appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton).enabled
error: property 'enabled' not found on object of type 'UIBarItem *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) po ((UIBarItem*)appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton).isEnabled
error: property 'isEnabled' not found on object of type 'UIBarItem *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) expr ((UIBarItem*)appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton).isEnabled
error: property 'isEnabled' not found on object of type 'UIBarItem *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) expr appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton.isEnabled
error: property 'isEnabled' not found on object of type 'UIBarButtonItem *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) po  appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton.isEnabled
error: property 'isEnabled' not found on object of type 'UIBarButtonItem *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) po  appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton.enabled
error: property 'enabled' not found on object of type 'UIBarButtonItem *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) expr  appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton.enabled
error: property 'enabled' not found on object of type 'UIBarButtonItem *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

How can I see the value of the property?

UPDATE: po @() does not work as well:

```
(lldb) po  @([[[appdelegate detailViewController] allMediaButton] isEnabled])
error: no known method '-isEnabled'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) po  @([(UIBarItem)[[appdelegate detailViewController] allMediaButton] isEnabled])
error: C-style cast from 'UIBarButtonItem *' to 'UIBarItem' is not allowed
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) po  @([(UIBarItem*)[[appdelegate detailViewController] allMediaButton] isEnabled])
error: no known method '-isEnabled'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression

(lldb) po  @([((UIBarItem*)[[appdelegate detailViewController] allMediaButton]) isEnabled])
error: no known method '-isEnabled'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
po @(scalar)
```

use

```
p scalar
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (po) print OBJECT like this, cause actually `enabled` property is not object type, but SCALAR. You can try `po @( your scalar value here )`.

And one more very important thing is try to do the following to get access to property without casting

```
po @([[[appdelegate detailViewController] allMediaButton] isEnabled])
```

that should work for you

Comment: I tried also expr command to evaluate the value. Did not work out as well.

Comment: try "po [NSNumber numberWithBool:is_enabled_vaue_here]"

Comment: the most easiest way in just NSLog:(@"isEnableValue = %@", [[[appdelegate detailViewController] allMediaButton] isEnabled] ? @"YES" : @"NO");

Comment: NSLog(appdelegate.detailViewController.allMediaButton.isEnabled ? @"Yes" : @"No"); works well, but the question is to do it using lldb